# Mongoose find element in array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I just started with Mongoose and having issues finding elements...

My schema contains an array of `subregions` from which I want to find the matching one by its `code`. The schema is the following:

```
 var schema = {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }

        ...

        subRegions: [{
            name: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            code: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
        }]

        ...

    };
```

I came up with

```
find({
    subRegions: {
        "$in": [{
            code: regionCode
        }]
    }
}).exec(...)
```

but this is not working...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your terminology is off as that structure is not a "multi-dimensional" array, since those have "arrays within arrays", hence "dimensions". This is just "objects" within an array.

So your problem here is a basic case of having the arguments the wrong way around. You don't need [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) just to search an array, but rather it takes a "list/array" of arguments to apply to the field.

In short, just lookup the field, and use ["dot notation"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation):

```js
.find({ "subRegions.code": regionCode }).exec(...);
```

You would only need `$in` for essentially an `$or` condition, looking up alternate values for `subRegions.code`, so you don't need that when there is only one value to match.

Comment: Thank you. Yes this is it. It was late and I mixed things up as I initially had ObjectId()s in that array...

Comment: THANKS!! You save my day