# How do I update an object from an outer function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, scope

Struggling with this mongoose function.  I'm trying to add an embedded object inside another embedded object, but it is adding the new bid object to the wrong place -  the new listings variable I created for my iterator. 
My for loops are trying to find the exact Listing to update so I think the action of assigning them is messing them up.  For instance if the Listing was `users[2].listings[10].bids` , how do I get to that object so I can update it?

```
 function create(req, res) {
   db.Listing.findById(req.params.listingId, function(err, foundListing) {
    // console.log(foundListing._id );
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error', err);
    }
     // res.json(foundListing);
     // get array of all users
    db.User.find({}, function(err, users) {
      // for loop iterates through all users' listings
      for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        let listings = users[i].listings
        // for loop iterates through all listings ids
        for (let j = 0; j < listings.length; j++) {
          // finds match
          // comparing _id with _id returning false. Not sure why, will return later
          if (listings[j].topic === foundListing.topic && listings[j].created === foundListing.created) {
            console.log("Found match: " + foundListing.topic);
            // get current user id to add to bid object
            db.User.findById(req.user, function(err, user) {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
              }
              var newBid = new db.Bid(req.body); // add data validation later
              newBid.uid = user._id
              // pushes new bid object into embedded listing
              listings[j].bids.push(newBid);
              listings[j].save(function(err, savedBid) {
               console.log('newBid created: ', newBid);
               console.log(listings[j]);
               res.json(newBid);
              });
            });
          }
        }
      }
    })
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
};
```

EDIT - Got this far, but now it doesn't seem like my array is saving.

```
function create(req, res) {
  db.Listing.findById(req.params.listingId, function(err, foundListing) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error:', err);
    }
    db.User.findOne({ 'listings._id': req.params.listingId }, function(err, foundUser) {
      // console.log(foundUser.listings);
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error: ', err);
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < foundUser.listings.length; i++) {
        // console.log(foundUser.listings[i]._id);
        if (foundUser.listings[i]._id == req.params.listingId) {
          console.log( 'found it! - ' + foundUser.listings[i].topic);
          var newBid = new db.Bid(req.body);
          // console.log(newBid)
          foundUser.listings[i].bids.push(newBid);
          console.log(foundUser.listings[i].bids)
          foundUser.listings[i].save(function(err, savedListing) {
            // console.log(foundUser.listings[i])
            if (err) {
              console.log('Error: ', err);
              return;
            }
              console.log('newBid created: ', newBid);
              console.log('savedListing', savedListing);
              res.json(newBid);
          })
        }
      }
    })
  });
};
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Where you do want the newBid to be placed? Try to provide more details

Comment: I have a Users collection that has embedded Listings. So 1 user can have many listings.  Then each Listing can have many bids (responses) which is embedded within the Listings. Because of the way it is set up, when a person responds with a bid, the function will search where that listing is (embedded within user) and once it finds that listing, that bid object will be pushed into that listing object, which was embedded within that user object.  My problem is that its not pushing into the original Listing array, but instead being pushed into the Listings variable array I created for my iterator

Comment: If your variable names collide then just rename one of them. `let userListings = users[i].listings`

Comment: It also looks a bit funny that you have something called `req.user` that you use to find a user by id..  But you just make the request to GET the user so that you can get the user id..  Don't you already have the user id in `req.user` or possibly `req.user.id` ?

Comment: Well my for loops are trying to find the exact Listing to update so I think the action of assigning them is messing them up.  For instance if the Listing was `users[2].listings[10].bids` , how do I get to that object so I can update it?

Comment: `users[i].listings[j].bids.push(newBid)`
Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, same issue. Doesn't seem like it is pushing to the correct object. Not seeing it anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have is pretty hard to grasp. I think you might be using the wrong tools to solve the problem. MongoDb and Mongoose seem to have pretty advanced querying, so that you can specify what exact user, listing etc. you're interested in.

I think it would be worth your time to look a bit at the documentation for [Mongoose queries](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) and maybe [MongoDb queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#projection) as well. The `.` used for `listings.id` in `db.User.findOne({ 'listings.id': req.params.listingId }` is [described here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#specify-a-query-condition-on-a-field-embedded-in-an-array-of-documents).

I can't really test that this code compiles or that it would work, because I don't know enough about your database models and so on, but something along these lines should be possible:

```
 function create(req, res) {
   db.Listing.findById(req.params.listingId, function(err, foundListing) {
    // use the power of mongo db and mongoose.
    // you can specify more exactly what you're looking for
    // in this case we're interested in ONE user that
    // has a listing with a specific id  
    // (if you still problems with comparing identical IDs, then that's a serious issue..
    //  maybe try logging req.params.listingId and check if it really exists
    // in your database.)
    db.User.findOne({ 'listings.id': req.params.listingId }, function(err, foundUser) {
      var newBid = new db.Bid(req.body); // add data validation later
      newBid.uid = foundUser._id

      // Old code: foundListing.bids.push(newBid) 

      // Change according to first question/answer at  http://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html
      // which was linked in the thread you linked to in comment.
      // The essence is that Mongoose doesn't get
      // notified about changes to arrays by default
      // To get around this you can update using "set"
      // but then you need both a value and an index:
      var oldBidsLength = foundListing.bids.length;
      foundListing.bids.set(oldBidsLength, newBid);     

      foundListing.save(function(err, savedBid) {
        // savedBid  =  saved LISTING? 
        console.log('newBid created: ', newBid);
        console.log('savedBid', savedBid);
        res.json(savedBid);
        }
      }
    })
  });
};
```

Things that may be off with this code example is things like if `db.User.findOne({ 'listings.id': req.params.listingId }` should be used with `listings._id`. I don't know enough about your models.

Comment: I appreciate the response and will try this out!  I looked around for examples and [this](https://coderwall.com/p/6v5rcw/querying-sub-documents-and-sub-sub-documents-in-mongoose) walk-through demonstrates something similar to my original post. So I've got bids embedded in listings embedded in users and I'm trying to add new bids depending on which Listing i am responding to (using AngularJS so listingId works)

Comment: Ok, yeah, I may be wrong about the the overlap between MongoDb syntax and Mongoose syntax. But it seems like it could be enough overlap for my suggestion to work, at least according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35214194/mongoose-find-element-in-array

Comment: Let me know how it goes and if you need something else. (It's bedtime here, though, so I won't answer for a while.)

Comment: Edited my response to include my progress above.. It console logs all the way down to savedListing, but at that point savedListing is undefined. I think I am not saving the array correctly and after reading [this] (https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1204) , I am not sure how to apply it to my code.

Comment: Nice find! It can be really hard to guess exactly how smart libraries/frameworks are. Some things just work "auto-magically", while other things don't. Anyway, in your link I saw one  solution having to do with  a wrong schema, but I don't know how to apply it to your code. But another one suggested a  simpler solution, namely to to tell Mongoose  "manually"  that an array had been updated. I've edited my answer to reflect that new knowledge. Hopefully that could fix the issue.

Comment: Btw. Even if this small Mongoose array-related thing was probably your issue all along (and the rest of your original code worked/works), I hope you see the benefits of restructuring the code to look more like the edits I suggested. Maybe the exact code doesn't work, but I'm pretty sure something like it can be done. Fewer steps -> easier to grasp + fewer places where things could go wrong -> easier to debug. In many (if not most) cases I think it would also be more performant to hand of most of the filtering/searching to the Database (mongodb / mongoose) layer. (Sorry if I sound too preachy).

Comment: You are amazing and thank you so much for your help and advice. This worked! `var oldLength = foundUser.listings[i].bids.length;
`             `foundUser.listings[i].bids.set(oldLength, newBid);`
          `foundUser.save(function(err, savedListing)` ... And yes.. I am done for the entire weekend

Comment: Awesome! You're welcome! Glad it finally worked. If you think my answer (with the update) answers your question I would much appreciate it if you would [mark the answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). That way other people coming here will also know the issue is resolved. Have a nice weekend!